# Session usage with login and prebuilt SessionManager class

Tags: php, session, authentication

I don't quite understand how I'm supposed to use [SessionManager](https://github.com/tedivm/phpsessionmanager).  I am trying to use this class to validate a log in so that the user form will not display, because I don't yet understand how to use Sessions on my own. I thought a pre-built class would help me to learn. Currently I have this:

```
$user = new User( $pdo );
$user->getByUserName( $_SERVER['username'] );
$user->logon( $_SERVER['password'] );

if ( $user->is_logged_on )
{
    //... Do logged in user stuff
}
else
    header( 'Location: /?error=Login%20Error%2E%20Please%20re%2Denter%20your%login%20information%2E' );
```

Currently, I'd have to enter the login information each time I go to the page, which is not how user logins work haha...  I'm trying to use the SessionManager to maintain that user login, but I don't really understand how.

Do I simply start a session with every page? Does the SessionManager class even have anything to do with checking sessions? or is it just for starting them? I'm still learning how to use User Authentication and PHP Sessions, so I'm new to this.

Do I need to add a method to check existing sessions:

```
if ( !isset( $_SERVER['loginsubmit'] ) )
{
    $user = new User( $pdo );
    $user->getByUserName( $_SERVER['username'] );
    if ( $user->logon( $_SERVER['password'] ) )
        SessionManager::sessionStart('mySessionName');
}
if ( !SessionManager::checkSession() )
{
    //...display login form
}
else
{
    //...display logged in user stuff
}
```

I'm extremely confused... maybe I'm over-thinking it... or maybe this wasn't the best example of how to use sessions.

**EDIT:** FYI, I'm not really asking how to code the method, I know how to create a session and check if it *exists*, I'm just not understanding how sessions are used for user authentication, so I chose to try and learn from a pre-built example. I can read the PHP manual all day long about how to actually code sessions.

Comment: There isn't one, what I'm asking is *do I need to add one*. Or does the simple existence of the session indicate user logon once it's created, given the validating nature of the class linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way:

// On pages:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['isLogin']) && $_SESSION['isLogin'] != true){
    // redirect to login page
} else {

    // redirect to login page and
    // set $_SESSION['isLogin'] = true when login verify 

}
```

PS. same go with the library you refer in your question use the library function to start secure session and verify session.

Comment: So, the session needs to exist whether logged in or not, then the session variables (username etc) are added after actual login occurs, and my library is simply there to maintain session security? If I have this right, I need to run `SessionManager::sessionStart('mySessionName');` at the start of each user interaction, and simply set/check `$_SESSION['username']` separately? Then to log out, I delete `$_SESSION['username']`.

Comment: also, did you mean to have both conditions point to the login script? Or was that a typo?

Comment: @Dexter Sorry for delay response hopefully you have a solution by now.

>> For your first comment your observation is truly correct. 
>> On second comment it is the same condition one is checking if the session is present and other is checking if it have the proper value.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. My script seems to be working and now I understand much better. Just wanted to confirm. Thanks!